# Boundary points and minimum distance

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider the metric space $(C,d)$, given that $\partial X$ is the set of boundary points of $X \subset C.$ Does this directly imply that, for every $x \in X,$ there exists a $y^* \in \partial X$ such that $y^* =$ argmin$_{y\in \partial X} d(x,y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true in general, not without some extra hypotheses. Here is a counterexample: let $C$ be the real plane with the positive $x$-axis removed, ie

$$C = \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(x,0) : x > 0\}$$

and let $d$ be the standard metric. Then, let $X$ be the halfplane to the left of the line $x = 1$; ie

$$X = \{(x,y) : x < 1\} \cap C$$

Then $\partial X = \{(x,y) : x = 1 \text{ and } y \neq 0\}$.

Let $x = (0,0) \in X$, in which case $d(x,\partial X) = 1$ but there is no $y \in \partial X$ such that $d(x,y) = 1$. Here is an illustration:

[image]

One hypothesis you might add is *completeness*, meaning any cauchy sequence in $C$ has a limit. This is not true of the above $C$, because a sequence which "should" converge to a point on the positive $x$-axis in fact does not converge at all, because those points have been removed from the space. The space has "holes", you might say.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the reply.
In your answer above, you said that when $x=(0,0), d(x,\partial X) = 1$, could you elaborate on this point? Since $\partial X = \{(x,y) : x = 1 \text{ and } y \neq 0\}$, it seems to me that all we can have is $\inf_{y \in \partial X} d(x,y)=1$?

Comment: For a point $x$ and a subset $Y$, it is generally understood that $d(x,Y) = \inf d(x,y)$. If you require that $\min d(x,y)$ exists (more than just $\inf$), then there will trivially exist a point $y \in Y$ to achieve the minimum by definition

Comment: Thanks so much, that's very helpful!